# Classic Statistics Probability in R Draws

Tags: r, simulation

```
data=data.frame("type" = c("a","b","c","d"),
        "p"=c(.2,.47,.1,.23))
```

I am largely teaching myself statistics and there is the classic example of picking a letter or colored ball at random but with a certain probability. Say I have dataframe 'data' and I have four types indicated by a-d. Each letter has a probability of being chosen. How can I make a simulation to see the distribution of letters chosen if say I pick 100 letters?

Answer (score 1):

```
sample(data$type, 100, replace = T, prob = data$p)
```

The parameters are:

- the vector from which you wish to sample
- the number of draws
- a specification of whether the draws should be with or without replacement; by default this is `FALSE` but would give an error in this case since you can't draw 100 objects from 4 without replacement
- an optional specification of the probability weights; note that they don't have to be normalized to add to 1, though it's fine that yours are

---

To get a more holistic sense of the distribution, you might try:

```
mysample <- sample(data$type, 100, replace = T, prob = c(3, 1, 1, 1))
table(mysample)    # tabulate simulated draws
plot(mysample)     # make a bar graph of simulated draws
```